# Apache sometimes hangs while responding to requests

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, xampp, slow-connection, apache-traffic-server

I have an Apache web server working in windows environment. It is working smoothly, but sometimes even when on low load, is fails to serve the said requests but quickly loads the page when user refresh the URL in the browser.

my mpm_winnt_module configuration is as follows-

```
    ThreadLimit            3072
    ThreadsPerChild        3072
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0

KeepAlive Off
```

and also

```
AcceptFilter http none
AcceptFilter https none
```

In Apache's, mod_status it is showing plenty of workers idle. But still page load gets halted sometimes and sometimes it gets timed out but soon it loads smoothly upon refresh.

Comment: Can you share details on why you change the default setting for `KeepAlive` and `AccepFilter` ?

Comment: @luuk regarding my issue, I googled my issue and as per the relevant answers and suggestions, I made necessary changes to the apache configuration. Apache is still working fine but problem still persists even after changes made to the configuration.

Comment: @luuk do tell me if I am anywhere wrong with the configuration.

Comment: The default for [KeepAlive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#keepalive) is `On`. When you changed it, for whatever reason, this influences the number of connections, which has influence on the number of threads. The complete config, and the actual usage of this server (WordPress or API server, are different usage) are important factors which have influence on the asked question. (I am not claiming to know the answer to your question)